# protobuf within avro encoded message on kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, protocol-buffers

Wanted to know if there is a better way to solve the problem that we are having. Here is the flow:

Our client code understands only protocol buffers (protobuf). On the server side, our gateway gets the protobuf and puts it onto Kafka.

Now avrò is the recommended encoding scheme, so we put the specific protobuf within avro (as a byte array) and we put it onto the message bus. The reason we do this is to avoid having to do entire protobuf->avro conversion.

On the consumer side, it reads the avro message, gets the protobuf out of it and works on that.

How reliable is protobuf with Kafka? Are there a lot of people using it? What exactly are the advantages/disadvantages of using Kafka with protobuf?

Is there  a better way to handle our use case/scenario?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Kafka doesn't differentiate between encoding schemes since at the end every message flows in and out of kafka as [binary](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#messages).
2. Both Proto-buff and Avro are binary based encoding schemes, why would you want to wrap a proto-buff inside an Avro schema, when you can directly put the proto-buff message into Kafka?

Comment: thanks Dinesh!  To answer (2), I wasn't sure if protobuf with Kafka is being used extensively.   Kafka recommends Avro and wasn't sure if protobuf + kafka is being used in production in general. Any insights?

Comment: It is not as widely used compared to Avro. In-fact Kafka creators have voiced their support for Avro as the preferred data format, the reason behind that is explained here http://www.confluent.io/blog/stream-data-platform-2/

Comment: thanks! Yes, I looked at that and thats why I decided may be protobuf within an avro makes more sense - just to keep it consistent with Confluent recommendation.    are you aware of any in-production uses of kafka with protobuf?

Comment: The moment you drift away from Avro's inbuilt types and use a custom type (byte[] of protobuf), you lose most of it's functionalities esp., schema evolution. So, I'd recommend to either use protobuf directly in kafka or bite the bullet and perform the transformation from protobuf -> avro on the producer side. I'm not aware of any production cases of kafka + protobuf, sorry.